# LINQ for multiple count operations

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq

@gfrizzle pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474817/linq-count-on-multiple-columns) that LINQ to SQL generates independent SELECT statements for each count operation when given LINQ like this:

```
From d in db
Group d.a.AuditStatus By d.a.DateCreated Into Group
Select _
    DateIssued = DateCreated, _
    TotalAudits = Group.Count(), _
    TotalCancelled = Group.Count(Function(x) If(x = "Cancelled", True, False)), _
    TotalComplete = Group.Count(Function(x) If(x = "Complete", True, False)), _
    TotalIssued = Group.Count(Function(x) If(x = "Issued", True, False)), _
    TotalPending = Group.Count(Function(x) If (x = "Pending", True, False)), _
    Remaining = 0
```

As the data in question gets large enough, this could easily result in a huge performance hit.  I know I could rewrite this as a native SQL query, but I'm using several features of LINQ in other places (like the ability to break my where clause up) that I don't want to give up if I can avoid it.  Any other workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka!  I finally got it.  It's a logical problem in the way the underlying SQL is constructed.  There *is* no way to write that LINQ as a single pass SQL query because COUNT operations only look at the number of rows regardless of any WHERE style clause.

The solution is to mimic a COUNT/WHERE combination by using SUM instead.  This LINQ query creates a single pass SQL query using SUM(CASE WHEN) columns.

```
    From d In resultSet
    Group d By key = d.a.DateCreated Into g = Group
    Select _
        TotalAudits = g.Sum(Function(x) 1), _
        TotalCancelled = g.Sum(Function(x) If(x.a.AuditStatus = "Cancelled", 1, 0)), _
        TotalComplete = g.Sum(Function(x) If(x.a.AuditStatus = "Complete", 1, 0)), _
        TotalIssued = g.Sum(Function(x) If(x.a.AuditStatus = "Issued", 1, 0)), _
        TotalPending = g.Sum(Function(x) If(x.a.AuditStatus = "Pending", 1, 0)), _
        Remaining = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you ran another query using a compound key to get the subgroups, it would translate to more efficient SQL.  I'm not up on my VB Linq syntax, so consider this pseudo code:

```
From d in db 
Group d.a.AuditStatus By New With { d.a.AuditStatus, d.a.DateCreated } Into Group 
Select ...
```